# Spring Boot REST Controller as External Dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a SpringBoot REST service (App 1) that exposes some end points to return some data. You can think the application as a monitoring agent.

Any other application should be able to include my SpringBoot REST service as Maven dependency.

However, when I tested this on a second application (App 2), the REST endpoints of my SpringBoot REST service (App1 included as Maven Dependency) is not getting mapped and therefore not accessible.

What is the correct way?

Comment: why do you want it as dependency? just keep it running in another port and access it whereever you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something like this some time ago.

In you external dependencies you might want to remove the **Spring Boot Maven plugin** because you don't want executable jar.

Then add the jar as dependency to your project and make sure you scan it.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.your.project", "com.external.dependency"})
```

Comment: how we can implement this in gradle??? because when i am using jar as dependency in my another project, dependency is unresolved